# Redirecting to clean urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Currently I'm trying to redirect my website which has unfriendly *seo links*. I've added the ability to where the urls are sterilized.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will take you to the post page if you manually go to http://example.com/page/xxx however I want it to automatically redirect to that page even when you go to http://example.com/page.php?id=xxx how can I achieve this?

***EDIT:*** I found a way to do this successfully with **php** how ever it takes a second to load the page, and probably uses server resources that are beyond not needed.

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (strpos($actual_link, 'page.php?id=') !== false) {   
   header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/page/'.$_GET['id'].'' ) ;
}
```

I guess it will work for now though..

Comment: Yes you can do it.and I think it is so comfortable  I.:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573977/rewrite-url-to-php-page-without-parameters